# How do we set maximum_bad_records when loading a Bigquery table from dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is there a way to set the maximum number of bad records when writing to BigqueryIO? It seems to keep the default at 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this time, unfortunately, we don't provide a way to directly set the value of `configuration.load.maxBadRecords` in relation to `BigQueryIO` in Cloud Dataflow.

As a workaround, you should be able to apply a custom `ParDo` transform that filters "bad records" before they are passed to `BigQueryIO.Write`. As a result, BigQuery shouldn't get any "bad records". Hopefully, this helps.

If the ability to control `configuration.load.maxBadRecords` is important to you, you are welcome to file a feature request in the [issue tracker of our GitHub repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues).

Comment: OK. Do you have an example of how to do the specification in .fromQuery? That seems to be a read method, and not a write (load) method.

Comment: @DavorBonaci could you elaborate on how one would go about filtering bad records? I asked that question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35180012/validating-rows-before-inserting-into-bigquery-from-dataflow (is there a way to validate a `TableRow` against a `TableSchema`, for example?)

Comment: Ack. Let's continue the conversation there.